# How to convert all hyphenation patterns from Unicode to T1 in lualatex?

Tags: luatex, hyphenation, font-encodings

I'm trying to use *lualatex* with old, 8-bit, non-Unicode fonts:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}
\usepackage{t1enc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\def\myhelvetica{\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter\language=\l@hungarian
\showhyphens{árvíztűrő türkörfúrógép}
\hrule
{\Huge Helló, Wörld, árvíztűrő}
\hrule
{\Huge Helló, Wörld, árvízt\H{u}r\H{o}}
\hrule
{\myhelvetica\Huge Helló, Wörld, árvíztűrő}
\hrule
\end{document}
```

Everything works except that `\showhyphens` shows incorrect hyphenation:

- ár-víz-tű-rő would be correct, `\showhyphens` shows something else. (When using *lualatex* and *fontspec*, this is also hyphenated correctly.) **I want `\showhypens` to show ár-víz-tű-rő here in lualatex, even without fontspec.**
- tü-kör-fú-ró-gép is hyphenated correctly.

I suspect that the problem is caused by the letters ő and ű, which are at different positions in Unicode and T1 encodings. (All other letters, including ó and é are at the same position.)

Is there a way to convert all hyphenation patterns from Unicode to T1 encoding, something I can add between `\documentclass` and `\begin{document}`? I won't be using *fontspec* or any Unicode font in this compilation. The files containing the hyphenation patterns are probably correct, I just want *lualatex* to load them with a different encoding (T1), or do an in-memory encoding conversion after having loaded them. It's OK for me if some extra Lua code has to be written to make this happen.

I know and I've checked that it works in *pdflatex* out of the books. However, in this question I'm looking for a way to make it work in *lualatex*. I'm not looking for advice whether I should be using *pdflatex* or *lualatex*: for the purposes of this question I'm committed to *lualatex*.

Comment: From my point of view, nothing's wrong.

Comment: Why do you want to use `lualatex` when not using `fontspec`? In such qa case use simply `pdflatex`

Comment: @Herbert: In this question I'd like to understand how *lualatex* works, I won't necessarily be using it instead of *pdflatex* in the future. One reason is there are some packages which work with *lualatex* and not *pdflatex*. Also I want to make sure that my documents and the packages I've developed will work with *lualatex*, in case someone is compiling them with *lualatex*.

Comment: Ok, but using `lualatex` with the _old_ stuff `luainputenc` and `t1enc` makes _no_ sense!

Comment: @Herbert: I understand that in *pdflatex* `\showhyphens{ár-víz-tű-rő}` is correct, and if I need a quick solution now, I should use *pdflatex*. However, in this question I'd like to know how to make it work with *lualatex*, and I'm looking for advice on how to do it. I disagree with you that it makes no sense. For me it makes perfect sense. Fortunately, to make it work with *lualatex* we (users of this site) don't have to agree on what makes sense.

Comment: If the hyphenation is incorrect, then drop a line to the maintainer of the hyphen pattern Peter Szabo (pts@fazekas.hu). Then use `\hyphenation{tür-kör-fú-ró-gép}` in the preamble

Comment: @Herbert: Hyphenation patterns are correct, but *lualatex* has loaded them using the wrong encoding. (When using *lualatex* and *fontspec*, everything works correctly.) There is nothing to fix in the hyphenation pattern file. I've clarified this in the question now.

Comment: Ok, I see. `luainputenc` was developed  when LuaTeX came out, years ago and nobody needs this package today.

Comment: I really would not do this at all, but you don't need to convert anything all the hyphenation patterns are already available for T1 just input the file you would use for pdftex (in luatex you can do this at run time) especially if you are really using latin modern which is available as opentype there is no reason to do this at all

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Cool, thanks for the tip! I'll take a look how I can `\input` the hyphanation pattern file to produce the `\patterns` in the correct encoding, and I'll also take a look how I can modify `lang.patterns` from Lua code after they have been defined.

Comment: It would be tricky and not worth the effort to do: `I want \showhypens to show ár-víz-tű-rő here in lualatex, even without fontspec.` , `\showhyphens` is a low level debugging command so you should be prepared for it to show the internal encodings used. You have forced luatex to convert the Unicode inpiut to T1 and tex's internal character and box and hyphenation is all using that encoding so that is what you see in `\showhyphens` it will look like random characters if you read it with a UTF-8 encoded terminal but those characters if printed using a T1 encoded font come out as the right thing.

Comment: @pts I think babel should do this automatically if you switch language using babel rather than a primitive `\language`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I've just verified it with `\usepackage[hungarian]{babel}` instead of `\language=\@hungarian`: the output of `\showhyphens{árvíztűrő}` is still wrong.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I don't care much that the characters on the terminal are wrong (they already are). My problem is that the hyphens are inserted incorrectly: it should be ár-víz-tű-rő or ár-víz-tX-rX, but it is ár-víztXrX.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88131/discussion-between-david-carlisle-and-pts).

Comment: “TeX’s algorithm for hyphenation gives up when it encounters an `\accent` command” https://texfaq.org/FAQ-hyphenaccents

Comment: @HenriMenke: Thank you for trying to help! There is no `\accent` in my example, and my use of `\usepackage{t1enc}` is equivalent to `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`. My observations are also inconsistent with *TeX's algorithm for hyphenation gives up*, because TeX hyphenates words some accents correctly, but not others. The linked document doesn't provide advice which is relevant or could help for this question.

Comment: @pts ő and ű are built using `\accent` because they are not mapped in T1.

Comment: @HenriMenke: In fact, ő and ű are mapped in T1.

Comment: Glad you got something working, but I would still say that the correct answer would be not to use luainputenc and T1 encoding which between them disable almost all of luatex's font handling.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: As a document author I'll use *pdflatex* with old-style fonts, and I'll use *lualatex* with *fontspec* fonts. However, as a package developer I have no control over how my users are using the package, so I want to make it work correctly for my users in as many environments as possible. (For this I need to understand how non-ASCII characters and hyphenation work in various environments.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this in the meantime. Here is the solution (with important lines indicated with a trailing `%%`):

```
% pl.tex, works with modern pdflatex and lualatex in TeX Live 2019.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}  %%
\usepackage{lmodern} \normalfont
\usepackage{t1enc}
\let\kanjiskip\hsize  %%
\usepackage[hungarian]{babel}
\expandafter\let\expandafter\CCC\csname @tempcnta\endcsname  %%
\CCC128 \loop\ifnum\CCC<159 \ifnum\lccode\CCC=0 \lccode\CCC\CCC\fi  %%
  \advance\CCC1 \repeat  %%
\CCC160 \loop\ifnum\CCC<190 \ifnum\lccode\CCC=0 \lccode\CCC\CCC\fi  %% 
  \advance\CCC1 \repeat  %%
\CCC192 \loop\ifnum\CCC<256 \ifnum\lccode\CCC=0 \lccode\CCC\CCC\fi  %%
  \advance\CCC1 \repeat  %%
\begin{document}
\showhyphens{árvíztűrő tükörfúrógép}
\hrule width \hsize
\bigskip
\vbox{\Huge\hsize7em\hrule\noindent . . . . . bababababababa\hrule}
\bigskip
\vbox{\Huge\hsize7em\hrule\noindent . . . . . bábábábábábábá\hrule}
\bigskip
\vbox{\Huge\hsize7em\hrule\noindent . . . . . bőbőbőbőbőbőbő\hrule}
\bigskip
\vfill\hrule width\hsize
\end{document}
```

It hyphenates as expected: ba-ba-..., bá-bá-..., bő-bő-..., ár-víz-tű-rő tü-kör-fú-ró-gép.

FYI here is my original example, which works with *pdflatex* only:

```
% p.tex, works with pdflatex only.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern} \normalfont
\usepackage{t1enc}
\usepackage[hungarian]{babel}
\begin{document}
\showhyphens{árvíztűrő tükörfúrógép}
\hrule width \hsize
\bigskip
\vbox{\Huge\hsize7em\hrule\noindent . . . . . bababababababa\hrule}
\bigskip
\vbox{\Huge\hsize7em\hrule\noindent . . . . . bábábábábábábá\hrule}
\bigskip
\vbox{\Huge\hsize7em\hrule\noindent . . . . . bőbőbőbőbőbőbő\hrule}
\bigskip
\vfill\hrule width\hsize
\end{document}
```

Explanation of the solution (*pl.tex*):

- Input files are in UTF-8 encoding, text fonts are in [T1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cork_encoding) encoding.
- `\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}`: *luainputenc.sty* is needed instead of *inputenc.sty*, otherwise with *lualatex* the letter *ő* and *ű* wouldn't appear at all.
- `\let\kanjiskip\hsize`: This makes *hyph-hu.ec.tex* be loaded instead of *hyph-hu.tex* by *loadhyph-hu.tex*, loaded indirectly by *babel.sty*. We need *hyphu-hu.ec.tex*, because it contains the hyphenation patterns in the T1 encoding (rather than UTF-8).
- `\lccode\CCC\CCC`, e.g. `\lccode"AE="AE`: Without this *lualatex* wouldn't recognize ő and ű as letters when hyphenating. `AE` is the hex code of ő in T1 encoding.
- In the console log output of *pdflatex* in an UTF-8 terminal window, the `\showhyphens` line contains all accented characters incorrectly: �r-v�z-t�-r� t�-k�r-f�-r�-g�p . Nevertheless, the words are correctly hyphenated.
- In the console log output of *lualatex* in an UTF-8 terminal window, the `\showhyphens` line contains the some (ő and ű) accented characters incorrectly: ár-víz-t¶-r® tü-kör-fú-ró-gép. Nevertheless, the words are correctly hyphenated. The reason why ő and ű are incorrect is because the console log output shows characters in T1 encoding (mapped to UTF-8), and ő and ű are the characters which have a different position in T1 vs Unicode.

Comment: Have you tried ``\showhyphens{\detokenize{árvíztűrő tükörfúrógép}}``, I can't test on TL2018 because I did not install all language support. Works on TL2016 but this is old lualatex.

Comment: @jfbu: Thanks for tip! I'll try this and some others, and report back with my findings.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer the question directly, but it shows some insights on how I debugged `\showhyphens`.

I was using this source file:

```
% Compile it with lualatex.
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}
\usepackage{t1enc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[hungarian,english]{babel}
\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{hungarian}
% Correct hyphenation is ár-víz-tű-rő tü-kör-fú-ró-gép
\showhyphens{árvíztűrő tükörfúrógép}  % Incorrect.
\showhyphens{árvízt\string űr\string ő türkörfúrógép}  % Correct.
{\lccode\string`X="0171 \lccode\string`Y="0151
\lowercase{\showhyphens{árvíztXrY türkörfúrógép}}}  % Correct.
\edef\zzzz{ő}
\typeout{D1: \meaning ő}
\typeout{D2: \number\string`ő}
\typeout{D3: \meaning\zzzz}
\typeout{D4: \expandafter\number\expandafter\string\expandafter`\zzzz}
\hrule
{\Huge árvíztűrő árvíztűrő árvíztűrő árvíztűrő árvíztűrő árvíztűrő
árvíztűrő árvíztűrő árvíztűrő árvíztűrő árvíztűrő árvíztűrő
árvíztűrő árvíztűrő árvíztűrő árvíztűrő árvíztűrő árvíztűrő
árvíztűrő árvíztűrő árvíztűrő árvíztűrő árvíztűrő árvíztűrő
árvíztűrő árvíztűrő árvíztűrő árvíztűrő árvíztűrő árvíztűrő
árvíztűrő árvíztűrő árvíztűrő árvíztűrő árvíztűrő árvíztűrő
árvíztűrő árvíztűrő árvíztűrő árvíztűrő árvíztűrő árvíztűrő}
\hrule
\end{document}
```

The console log output:

```
D1: macro:->\H o
D2: 337
D3: macro:->®
D4: 174
```

My explanation:

- D2 shows that ő has character code 337, which corresponds to U+0151, the letter ő in Unicode.
- D1 shows that ő is an active character which expands to `\H o`.
- D3 shows that the full expansion of ő (by expanding `\H o` as much as possible) is ®.
- D4 shows that the character code of ® is 174, which corresponds to the letter ő in the T1 encoding (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cork_encoding).
- This is in line with what I've suspected in the question: I suspect that the problem is caused by the letters ő and ű, which are at different positions in Unicode and T1 encodings. (All other letters, including ó and é are at the same position.)
- When the argument of `\showhyphens` is expanded, ő is transformed to ®, and we get incorrect hyphenation. Hyphenation patterns are in Unicode in *lualatex*.
- When the argument of `\showhyphens` is expanded, `\string ő` is transformed to ő, and we get correct hyphenation.
- Similarly, with the `\lccode` trick above we can get a non-expanding ő (U+0151, Unicode 337) token, and we get correct hyphenation.
- The effect of `\selectlanguage{hungarian}` is different from the effect of `\makeatletter\language=\l@hungarian`, and the first one is correct. The second one prevents the tű-rő hyphenation.
- Even if we do `\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}` and `\usepackage{lmodern}` before loading `babel`, hyphenation patterns will be in Unicode.
- The file *hyph-hu.tex* contains Hungarian hyphenation patterns in Unicode (UTF-8), *loadhyph-hu.tex* takes care of loading it without encoding changes. Please note that there are other input files (e.g. *hyph-hu.ec.tex*) and there are encoding conversions, but they are not used.

Some more info on how *lualatex* loads the hyphenation patterns:

```
\makeatletter
\def\bbl@trace#1{}
\input luababel.def  % Loads language.dat and defines \l@hungarian.
\language=\l@hungarian
\input loadhyph-hu.tex  % Defines \patterns{...} in Unicode (UTF-8).
\lefthyphenmin=1
\righthyphenmin=1
\showhyphens{árvíztűrő türkörfúrógép}  % Correct.
\@@end
```

Normally we wouldn't have to load luababel.def and loadhyph-hu.tex manually, `\usepackage[hungarian]{babel}` would take care of that.